# Java MIDI sequencer never ends

Tags: java, midi

I'm running some MIDI code from a tutorial, but the program never terminates. It seems the MIDI sequencer never stops running, even though it reports that the length is 0.625s.

Do I need to do something else to make the sequencer stop?

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MyMidiPlayer {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyMidiPlayer player = new MyMidiPlayer();
        player.setUpPlayer(4);
    }

    public void setUpPlayer(int numOfNotes)
    {
        try {
            Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            sequencer.open();
            Sequence sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
            Track track = sequence.createTrack();

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfNotes; i++)
            {
                track.add(makeEvent(144, 1, i+48, 100, i));
                track.add(makeEvent(128, 1, i+48, 100, i + 2));
            }

            sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
            sequencer.setTempoInBPM(88);
            System.out.println("Playing (length=" + sequencer.getMicrosecondLength()/1000000f + "s)...");
            sequencer.start();

            while (true) {
                // Never returns false, so the program never quits
                if (!sequencer.isRunning()) {
                    sequencer.close();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public MidiEvent makeEvent(int command, int channel, int note, int velocity, int tick)
    {
        MidiEvent event = null;
        try {
            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(command, channel, note, velocity);
            event = new MidiEvent(a, tick);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return event;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was going to delete this, but I'll leave it up and post the answer. It seems you need to call `sequencer.getMicrosecondPosition()` in the `while` loop. Presumably this updates some variable in the sequencer class which then makes `isRunning` correctly return `false` when the position matches the value returned by `getMicrosecondLength`.

So specifically:

```
while (true) {
    if (!sequencer.isRunning()) {
        sequencer.close();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    sequencer.getMicrosecondPosition();
}
```